# Splitting a match info in a variable

Tags: powershell

I am trying to split a match info that is stored in a variable. This is the match name

```
"Desktop\brif\number999.txt:1:2;2"
```

It's stored in the variable `$z`. I am running the following command:

```
$z.Line.Split(':')[2] #returns blank
$z.Line.Split(':'[2]) #returns 2;1
```

My intention is that the split returns me the 1.

The output of `[int[]][char[]]$z.Line | %{'{0:x2} {1}' -f $_, [char]$_}` 
is

```
32 2
3b ;
31 1
```

Comment: `$z.Line.Split(':')[1]` should give you the desired result. If it doesn't, please show the output of `$z.GetType().FullName`.

Comment: it does not return anything, the output of the ```$z.GetType().FullName ``` command is "Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MatchInfo"

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show the output of `$z.Line | Format-Hex` (or `[int[]][char[]]$z.Line | %{'{0:x2} {1}' -f $_, [char]$_}` if you don't have a recent-enough PowerShell version).

Comment: Depending on your unknown context it makes IMO mores sense to modify the RegEx to contain a capture group separating the desired content firsthand.

Comment: I will take any alternative its its more efficient

Answer (score 0):

have you tried

```
"Desktop\brif\number999.txt:1:2;2" | Out-String
```

or

```
$st1 = [string]$z.Substring(29,3) ; Write-Host $st1 # Substring(index,length)
```

Comment: um, er, WHY? [*frown*] that is already a string and `Out-String` sometimes adds ... junk ... to the stuff it outputs. extra line feeds, for instance ... ick!

Answer (score 0):

If your full match output is

```
Desktop\brif\number999.txt:1:2;2
```

and you want the `1` from that output, that is the line number of the match, so you'd get it like this:

```
$z.LineNumber
```

If the line of your match is actually `2;1` (as your debug output says), i.e. your full match looks like this:

```
Desktop\brif\number999.txt:1:2;1
```

and you want the last `1` from that match, you'd do this:

```
$z.Line.Split(';')[1]
```